# domain name is getting replaced with github.com in github ouath call

Tags: node.js, reactjs, oauth, passport.js, github-api

```
http://**XYZ.com**/login/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F**XYZIP**%3A3000%2Fauth%2Fgithub%2Fcallback&scope=user%3Aemail&client_id=34940ae24cfd171d449a4
```

When I try to use domain name instead of IP on github oauth app callback url its giving me an error...

If I change it to:

```
http://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F**XYZIP**%3A3000%2Fauth%2Fgithub%2Fcallback&scope=user%3Aemail&client_id=34940ae24cfd171d449a4
```

Then it will work but because of different callback URL in oauth it will show me mismatch callback URL.

Basically I am calling from react app front end and node `JS` back end and passport-git-hub that is in back-end

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour. When you login through a third party auth service They will call THEIR service and redirect to your service with a session key.

So, what happens is.

- There is a `Login` button, user clicks it
- It redirects to google/github/facebook login page where user puts the username and password and presses login.
- If user authenticated it generates a session key and sends that session key with additional info(for example profile) to your callback page.
- Your callback deserializes the request and generates the user session and profile object and such.
- When you open your route passport middleware checks if the session is there, if it's there goes to `next()` otherwise sends some error as response.

Maybe I got the question completely wrong but this is some generalised flow.

Comment: actually on my server its running on xyz.com:3000 and then i have revered peroxided to 80 so that it can work on xyz.com. with xyz.com:3000 it is working normal. but with xyz.com its not working.